# Nodejs - url Parameter must be a string, not undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Everytime i navigate to the relativ path i get following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
at Url.parse (url.js:103:11)
```

My get method looks like:

```
app.get('/v1/locations', (req, res) => {
const fixieUrl = url.parse(process.env.FIXIE_URL);
const requestedUrl= url.parse('api.clashofclans.com' + req.path);

const options = {
    host: fixieUrl.hostname,
    port: fixieUrl.port,
    path: requestedUrl.href,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer **token**',
        'Proxy-Authorization': `Basic ${new Buffer(fixieUrl.auth).toString('base64')}`
    }
};
```

I definately added the .env file with the FIXIE_URL so what could it be?

Comment: did you try to console log process.env.FIXIE_URL

Comment: `console.log(process.env.FIXIE_URL)` before  `const fixieUrl =` and show is it ?

Comment: it prints out undefined... i also tried to restart the IDE and still shows me undefined

Comment: do you import url module https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `req.url` instead of `process.env.FIXIE_URL`

**Update**

It's better to separate these.

In the `.env` file set, and use these in `url.js`:

```
FIXIE_URL_HOST=someUrl
FIXIE_URL_PORT=80
```

Comment: hmm yes i did it now it is undefined - but why? :/

Comment: Which is line 103, is it const fixieUrl or const requestedUrl?

Comment: it is definately fixieUrl - the requestedUrl is defined

Comment: How FIXIE_URL looks in the .env file?

Comment: export FIXIE_URL=*someUrl*:80

Comment: Try without the asterisk.

Comment: haha it was meant to be without the stars, wanted just to clearify what is url and what the port

Answer (score 0):

base on your comment since `process.env.FIXIE_URL` is undefined. It means the env variable is not set. so to fix this you can do this when start ur node app

```
export FIXIE_URL='yourUrl' npm start // or however you start ur node app
```

or add this yourUrl in a constant file which you load it from there.

or save `export FIXIE_URL='yourUrl'` in your OS profile